# Around 1904, did the scientific community take the atomic hypothesis seriously?

Tags: physics, atomic-theory

The time when Thomson discovered electrons, around 1897, what did the scientific community think about the atomic hypothesis? Was there a majoritarian consensus that matter is made of indivisible neutral atoms and was that based on evidence?

Here is why I am asking this. As far as I know, Thomson gave his plum-pudding model in 1904 based on (1) the atoms are electrically neutral and (2) they contain negatively charged electrons. This suggests to me that it was clear that matter is not continuous but made of neutral atoms at that time. But as far as I know, Boltzmann was severely criticized for his belief in the atomic hypothesis. Please correct my facts.

Comment: It was actively developed but controversial, see [SEP, Atomism in Nineteenth-Century Physics](https://seop.illc.uva.nl/entries/atomism-modern/#AtoNinCenPhy):"*Ostwald, Duhem and Planck were inclined to take thermodynamics as the model of how science should proceed, maintaining a secure and productive relationship with experiment whilst avoiding hypotheses of the kind involved in atomism. The factor that is usually considered as turning the tables decisively in favour of the atomists is Jean Perrin's experiments on Brownian motion*". Those were done in 1908-09.

Comment: See [Why can Perrin's study of Brownian motion demonstrate the existence of atoms](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5996/264). Also, very well written, and historically and philosophically interesting, is the President's Address by Arthur William Rücker (1848−1915) on pp. 3−26 [= .pdf pages 130−153, if you download the entire volume to look at] of [**Report of the Seventy-First Meeting of the British Association for the Advancement of Science**](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/93257#page/127/mode/1up) (Glasgow, 11−18 September 1901; address given on 11 September 1901).

Comment: I am sure there was no such thing as "scientific community" at that time. Just not enough real scientists to form a community.

Comment: @markvs - given the number of letters flying around the UK alone by members of the Royal Society, I have to beg to differ. If anything, the 'community' was more unified and less fractured by sub-disciplines.

Comment: @JonCuster: Since this number is given (to whom?). perhaps you can share it and the source.

Comment: @markvs - according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Society, there were 400-500 Fellows of the Royal Society in the early 20th century. Don't forget that during that time there were 2 mail deliveries a day in the UK, and a letter posted in the morning would often get to the destination that afternoon. Almost as good as texting...

Comment: @JonCuster:  In 1989 and 1990 each, there we 17 new fellows of LRS.  That includes mathematicians and medical doctors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fellows_of_the_Royal_Society_elected_in_1900

Comment: @markvs - So? The total number of scientists was much smaller 100 years ago. (And they seem to in theory be able to elect up to 52 per year, and the UK is not quite as important relative to the world now as then).

Comment: @JonCuster: You claimed that there was a "community" of physicists in the LRS at the beginning of the 20th century who wrote lots of letters (to each other?) delivered twice daily (I heard about 12 times daily, but it does not matter). The fact is that the number of physicists at that time was very small and they did not form a community.

Comment: @markvs - I would suggest that the small number made it much easier to be a community - they all knew each other and were much less specialized than now. Perhaps your definition of community differs from mine.

Comment: @JonCuster: Yes, the definitions must be different. And yes, people then were less specialized than now.

Comment: @markvs You must have a strange definition of "community". Professional societies and academies of scientists (not yet so named) existed in Europe since the 17th century and scientists formed a community in the usual sense of the word (common interests, communication, cooperation, etc.). Newton and Leibniz belonged to it. Kevles has a book [The Physicists: The History of a Scientific Community in Modern America](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Physicists/lJrvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en), where the latter is tracked from 1850s.

Comment: @Conifold: Those communities consisted mostly of medical doctors. Yes, they had common interests with physicists.

Comment: That is the classic British scientific community: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFrdqQZ8FFc

Comment: @markvs No, these are: [The Royal Society of London for Improving Natural Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Society#History) and [British Association for the Advancement of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Science_Association). Sarcasm is a poor substitute for lack of arguments.

Comment: @markvs: *I am sure there was no such thing as "scientific community" at that time.* --- From many years of reading 1800s literature, my impression is that there was **much more** of a sense of "scientific community" then than now, when even sub-sub-disciplines are fractured two or three levels deeper. Then the communities were mostly separated according to country, although with few exceptions (e.g. China, middle east, etc.) most of the top people in any field and country were familiar with the top people elsewhere and in other scientific fields.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: Top people usually do not form communities. They may be members of various scientific societies but that is a totally different thing. Asking whether scientific community in 1904 has some opinion about something does not make sense because the community did not exist then (similar to the situation now). One can ask about the opinion of the top scientists X, Y, Z ...

Comment: @markvs: Perhaps the meaning has changed over time (as is the case with "science" and "calculus", each of which then had more inclusive meanings), because the phrase [**scientific community**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scientific+community%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899) was often used in 1800s literature.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: "Often"? Name 3 usages.

Comment: I think "the atomic hypothesis" and "models of the internal structure of the atom" are two distinct things. Let us not forget that the "the atomic hypothesis" has been around since the dawns of the 19th century in trying to set a foundation for chemical reactions.

Comment: @markvs The first three independent genuine 19th century usages from Dave Renfro's link: [1](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Scientific_Papers/BEgXAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22scientific+community%22&pg=PA304&printsec=frontcover) [2](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Minerva_Or_Literary_Entertaining_and/OFQ6AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22scientific+community%22&pg=PA234&printsec=frontcover) [3](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Archaeologist/ilw1AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22scientific+community%22&pg=PT33&printsec=frontcover). You can find many more if you sift further.

Comment: @RobertFurber: The phrase "scientific community" used in these texts have completely different meaning.  For example, the first link is about Darwin, the second link is about scientists in the US (which were mostly doctors at that time), and the third link is about the Journal "Science".

Comment: @markvs This is called "moving the goalposts".

Comment: @markvs: Just got back from being out of town the past few days . . . Regarding your last comment, I thought I addressed this with "Then the communities were mostly separated according to country" in an earlier comment.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: That is true. But alao inside the same country the "communities" were very mixed and consisted mostly of medical people, geographers and such. There was no "scientific community" whose majority would be interested in nuclear phisics.

Comment: @markvs: *would be interested in nuclear phisics* --- The OPs question is about the atomic hypothesis (often then called the molecular theory), not anything about the existence of (let alone structure of) the nucleus, and acceptance of this hypothesis, which is not the same thing as interest in it (I accept plate tectonics theory, but I'm not interested in it). These issues aside, the 1901 address by Rücker I cited seems to suggest a fairly widespread acceptance of the atomic hypothesis in 1901. (Note this is an address to the entire British Association, not to one of the sections.)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: OK,replace "nuclear" by "molecular". Still medical doctors or geographers or even Darwin-like biologists then would not be interested in it. Or even if they were, they would not be saying anything interesting about it. It is like now the scientists most interested in Climate Change are political scientists which have no knowledge of physics or statistics at all.